# m is not defined materialize css

Tags: materialize

I always get error "M is not defined" el is not defined

[codepen sample](https://codepen.io/hoogw/pen/XEPeBo)

if you open console, you will see the error

I first load jquery.min.js then load materialize.min.js  .css

then load my script.js below.

M is not recognized, which it should

why?

```
// init materialize tab
 var instance = M.Tabs.init(el, options);

  // Or with jQuery

 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tabs').tabs();

 });
```

This is html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12">
        <ul  class="tabs">
       <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test1">Test 1</a></li>
       <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#test2">Test 2</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3 disabled"><a href="#test3">Disabled Tab</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test4">Test 4</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
    <div id="test1" class="col s12">Test 1</div>
    <div id="test2" class="col s12">Test 2</div>
    <div id="test3" class="col s12">Test 3</div>
    <div id="test4" class="col s12">Test 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This usually indicates not correctly "including" the library JS *prior* to the script. That is, there is no `M` variable in scope (eg "no module injection") and `window.M` (aka "a global") has not been set.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the problem, it is version.

**Make sure you use version => 1.0.0.**

```
 https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js
```

If you use version <1.0.0 very likely you have error as 'M is not defined'

**Make sure you load jquery before materialize css !**

Also you must first define elem and options to init tab

```
// init materialize tab
     var elem = $('.tabs')
     var options = {}
     var instance = M.Tabs.init(elem, options);

  //or Without Jquery


    //var elem = document.querySelector('.tabs');
     var options = {}
     var instance = M.Tabs.init(elem, options);
```

Comment: Works for me! Thanks!

Comment: @hoogw in which file do you define the elem and options to init tab?

Comment: In version 1.0.0 jquery not required. https://codepen.io/j_holtslander/pen/ddmMdY